# Modifying a list when unpacking parameters

Tags: python, iteration

I've recently come accross a problem where I needed to find an elegant way to itterate through a list while having readable code. I discovered the 'unpacking'.

Assume I have a list : `l = [ ['param_1', 1] ['param_2',2] ]`

I used to iterate through this list as follows :

```py
for param in l:
  if param[0] == 'param_1':
    param[1] = 27
```

Now I am doing :

```py
for param_name, param_value in l:
  if param_name == 'param_1':
    param_value = 27
```

Though it is much more readable, the fact that I assign param_value to 27 doesn't change my list as it used to with the old method. Any idea why ? Couldn't find some answer on the internet.

Answer (score 2):

This is what [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) are for; you're trying to update the value associated with the string `param_1`.

```
l = [ ['param_1', 1], ['param_2',2] ]
d = dict(l)
# {'param_1': 1, 'param_2': 2}
```

Instead of iterating over the whole list, you can now set the value directly:

```
d['param_1'] = 27
# {'param_1': 27, 'param_2': 2}
```

Note that this will only work properly if your parameter names are all unique; identical names will all get collapsed into the same dictionary key.

Comment: will not work if first element is not unique

Comment: @AtlasBravoos I'm aware, but given that this appears to be a parameter list I'm assuming uniqueness.

Comment: @AtlasBravoos in this case a dictionary of lists should probably be used ;)

Answer (score 2):

You said *"Couldn't find some answer on the internet"*, the answer is in between the lines, indeed. In the official documentation, though, the [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) has all the basic stones to understand what's going on. This is related to objects' *mutability* and variables [name binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html).

In the first case,

```
for param in l:
    ...
```

, `param` is a list. Lists are mutable objects, containers which values can change.

When you change one of `param`'s values the way you do,

```
    param[1] = 27
```

, you're telling Python to modify the second value of the list `param` is *pointing* to.

On the other hand, in the second case,

```
for param_name, param_value in l:
    ...
```

, you're unpacking those lists inside `l` into the corresponding pair of (scalar) values, `param_name` and `param_value`. The values they are pointing to are *immutable* types (string, number), and you also "lost" the pointer to the containet/list they were in (ie, `param` in the first case).

Now, when you do `param_value = 27`, Python is actually creating a new space in memory to allocate `27` and `param_value` is now referring to that value, but *this is a different variable* -- same name `param_value` but different space in memory.

---

References:

- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html

Comment: This is really insightful thanks ! I actually couldn't understand what was really going on !